# Configuration of Office word add in local network

Tags: office-js

I want to provide a part of the functionality of a secure messaging product, which has a web interface as well  through the Word Addin. The product  is deployed in the local network and  transports documents after encrypting and signing them across the internet.

The challenge for me is that  to access the local implementation of the product we would need a LAN based web url that would be different for different client installations. For using it in the word add-in, this url has  to be set in the manifest, so that accessing the manifest would render the web-app within Word 2006 in a task pane.

Is there a way of achieving this ? I had visualised it as an installation time prompt for the base url  when the add-in is installed from Office Store - which should then be updated on the manifest - but could not find out how to achieve it in Office Addin.

Can you review this and suggest a way of implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to dynamically change the URL in the manifest after it is deployed to the Office Store. You also can't handle the installation event.

Off the top of my head, maybe you could require that all customers of the Word add-in create an account with your Internet based service. As part of the account sign-up, the customer provides the LAN URL. Every time the add-in is launched, the user is prompted to login (or create an account). After login, the add-in can then be redirected as needed. An IT pro would have to provide the URL, but it looks like that would be a requirement even if you could have prompted for it at installation time.